# Handling relocations at runtime

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, x86, code-analysis, jit

I am trying to build a basic `JIT` engine for understanding purpose.

Trying to do some of the basic concepts which I read about, Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>


void * fptr;
int (*_printf)(const char*,...);

int test1(void)
{
        int arr[100] = {0x0};
        _printf("In %s\n", __FUNCTION__);     << Segfault due to this printf call
        return 5;
}
int main()
{

        fptr = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                   MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);

        memset((unsigned char *)fptr, 0x90, 4096);
        printf("Address of printf = %p\n", &printf);
        _printf = printf;

        int (* testptr)(void);
        memcpy(fptr, (unsigned char *)&test1, 67);
        testptr = fptr;

        int i = test1();
        printf("ret = %d\n", i);
        i = 0x0;
        i = testptr();
        printf("ret = %d\n", i);
        return 0;

}
```

This example copies function test1() to another piece of executable memory and tries to execute it ( I am copying 67 bytes which is crude but should not matter in this example ).

I am able to execute the copied function if I do not call any external symbol from shared library ( i.e. printf in this case ), but the program faces a SIGSEGV when printf() is called from test1().

I think this is happening due to relative addresses being used i.e. the test1() will work when if it executed from its original location else all relative addresses will turn bad.

Here is what gdb says,

```
info registers

r15            0x0  0
rip            0x7ffff7ff7025   0x7ffff7ff7025
eflags         0x10202  [ IF RF ]
cs             0x33 51

(gdb) x/10bx $rip
0x7ffff7ff7022: 0xf3    0x48    0xab    0x48    0x8b    0x15    0x08    0x0a
0x7ffff7ff702a: 0x20    0x00
(gdb) 


gdb) x/67bx fptr 
0x7ffff7ff7000: 0x55    0x48    0x89    0xe5    0x48    0x81    0xec    0x90
0x7ffff7ff7008: 0x01    0x00    0x00    0xcc    0x8d    0xb5    0x70    0xfe
0x7ffff7ff7010: 0xff    0xff    0xb8    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0xba
0x7ffff7ff7018: 0x32    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x48    0x89    0xf7    0x48
0x7ffff7ff7020: 0x89    0xd1    0xf3    0x48    0xab    0x48    0x8b    0x15
0x7ffff7ff7028: 0x08    0x0a    0x20    0x00    0xbe    0x1d    0x08    0x40
0x7ffff7ff7030: 0x00    0xbf    0xf4    0x07    0x40    0x00    0xb8    0x00
0x7ffff7ff7038: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0xff    0xd2    0xb8    0x05    0x00
0x7ffff7ff7040: 0x00    0x00    0xc9
(gdb) 

And here is the test1() function, code is compiled with -O0

(gdb) disassemble/r test1 
Dump of assembler code for function test1:
   0x000000000040062c <+0>: 55  push   %rbp
   0x000000000040062d <+1>: 48 89 e5    mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400630 <+4>: 48 81 ec 90 01 00 00    sub    $0x190,%rsp
   0x0000000000400637 <+11>:    48 8d b5 70 fe ff ff    lea    -0x190(%rbp),%rsi
   0x000000000040063e <+18>:    b8 00 00 00 00  mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400643 <+23>:    ba 32 00 00 00  mov    $0x32,%edx
   0x0000000000400648 <+28>:    48 89 f7    mov    %rsi,%rdi
   0x000000000040064b <+31>:    48 89 d1    mov    %rdx,%rcx
   0x000000000040064e <+34>:    f3 48 ab    rep stos %rax,%es:(%rdi)
   0x0000000000400651 <+37>:    48 8b 15 08 0a 20 00    mov    0x200a08(%rip),%rdx        # 0x601060 <_printf>
   0x0000000000400658 <+44>:    be 1d 08 40 00  mov    $0x40081d,%esi
   0x000000000040065d <+49>:    bf f4 07 40 00  mov    $0x4007f4,%edi
   0x0000000000400662 <+54>:    b8 00 00 00 00  mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400667 <+59>:    ff d2   callq  *%rdx
   0x0000000000400669 <+61>:    b8 05 00 00 00  mov    $0x5,%eax
   0x000000000040066e <+66>:    c9  leaveq 
   0x000000000040066f <+67>:    c3  retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue ?

Compiling the code with `-fPIC -pie` does not help.

Comment: This code has very little to do with just-in-time code generation.  It bombs because the operand for the CALL instruction is always an offset, not an absolute address.  So it bombs because the offset is wrong after you move the code.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps not much to do with JIT per-se and I might be wrong to connect the two. The issue, this is something which I will need to do as part of my experiments. Any inputs on how this can be fixed ? I was thinking if we can find out shared library load address and then calculate address of printf = libc load address + offset.

Comment: I don't see any point in fixing this.  Decide what you really want to do first.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this ? I see a huge point in understanding and fixing this. I am not sure we need to keep commenting about non-technical aspects. If you think I am wrong in framing my question, I will go ahead and modify it as you suggest but lets not dismiss a valid technical question just because we are getting caught up in irrelevant semantics.